# Why my 19 digit number will be rounded to 17 digits

Tags: php, mysql, json

I got a transaction number of `6316732587130745043` (`19 digits`).
Since Integer would not be enough, I use in my mysql database `decimal(50,0)`

The value in the database is, however, `6316732587130745000` (`rounded to 17 digits`)

I got the transaction number from a server request:

```
$sendInfo = file_get_contents($server.$request);
$obj_sendInfo = json_decode($sendInfo);
$transaction = $obj_sendInfo->{'transaction'};
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: you have to specify length of integer part and decimal part, check its current value... example DECIMAL( 25, 2 )

Comment: Why would you use a decimal type for a transaction number? Are you planning to do arithmetic on it? Otherwise, why not a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `bigint` datatype. 8 bytes of storage I believe. That is what it is meant for. Binary not floating point, lean and mean storage.

```
create table ph345
(
    bi bigint not null
);
insert ph345(bi) values (6316732587130745043);
```

select * from ph345;

```
+---------------------+
| bi                  |
+---------------------+
| 6316732587130745043 |
+---------------------+
```

Mysql manual page on [Numeric Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: glad to help. Now mark some of those questions of yours as Answered with the green check mark :)

Comment: while changing to biginit makes the last two digits of $transaction not anymore "00", it contains a wrong value in the last 3 digits. There must be still a problem in php.

Comment: Could still not figure out how to solve that. Can anybody help?